# Create dataframe from list of lists

Tags: r

I have a list of lists, like this:

```
tweetsdata <- list(politician1=list(meanlikes=2, meanretweet=1), politician2=list(meanlikes=4, meanretweet=3))
```

My desidered output is a data frame `tweetsdata_df` with 3 columns, like this:

```
|  POLITICIAN | MEANLIKES | MEANRETWEETS |

| ----------- | --------- | ------------ |

| Politician1 |     2     |      1       |

| Politician2 |     4     |      3       |
```

If I do a simple `as.data.frame(tweetsdata)` the output is a dataframe with 1 obs. of 4 variables (politician1.meanlikes, politician1.meanretweet, politician2.meanlikes, politician2.meanretweet)

If I try to create the dataframe manually I don't know how to access the right variable:

```
tweetsdata_df <- data.frame(POLITICIANS=names(tweetsdata), MEANLIKES=???, MEANRETWEETS=???)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)

enframe(tweetsdata) |> unnest_wider(col="value")
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `purrr::map_dfr()`

```
library(purrr)

map_dfr(tweetsdata, f = ~.x, .id = "politician").

# A tibble: 2 × 3
  politician  meanlikes meanretweet
  <chr>           <dbl>       <dbl>
1 politician1         2           1
2 politician2         4           3
```